# Endomondo without autopause

Tags: bikeroutes, software, track-racing

Suppose I saved my training on Endomondo (android)  with `autopause` option **disabled**. I have my training stored and I can view it on the endomondo.com site.

But I want to "simulate" autopause i.e. I need to obtain the same (similar) statistics as when `autopause` is **enabled**. Is it possible?
Maybe I need to use "special" editing this track (maybe with other software? - what software?).

Comment: I'm not sure why do want to edit your own routes, can you elaborate more?

Comment: I'm thinking you're better off finding software that analyzes the gpx file and allows you to omit the pauses. I don't know if such software exists. The complexity of programmatically finding the pauses and rebuilding the GPX file without them make for a non-trivial task.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its off topic for this stack.  Please ask your question on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and use the Cycling tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it's highly possible, since you can export your routes to .gpx files and manipulate the timestamps.

A .gpx file is actually an xml file which is similar to html files with tags. Each tag tells you the current longitude, latitude, and the current time stamp.
You actually can edit the .gpx file with a text editor, i.e. notepad and edit the file by yourself. However, you need to know the exact long-lat where you want to "pause".

Comment: I think the OP wants to remove the pauses. They should be easy to spot, the trick is to adjust the other timestamps. As you say, technically possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write something in python to work directly on the gpx file. There are decent libraries for working with xml. An easier approach if you don't code (much) is to use [gpsbabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/) to convert to a csv file then your favourite spreadsheet. Then possibly gpsbabel again to get back to gpx depending on your analysis.

The edit probably won't have to change the data point timestamp but may have to do something about elapsed time. I think that's a separate field,  from memory.

Have a look at gis.stackexchange for gpx hacking advice.